# Is it possible to combine multiple .xcframework files into single .xcframeowork file?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I have 20-30 .xcframework files which I need to combine into single .xcframework to be delivered to client.

Out of them only 1 framework is static framework, all the rest are dynamic framework.

I have tried 'lipo' tool to combine frameworks, but it failed with errors.

Does anyone have any experience in this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS merge several framework into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843617/ios-merge-several-framework-into-one)

Answer (score 1):

No, xcframework can contain only variants of one framework inside it. As it was said at WWDC19: "XCFrameworks — for distributing multiple framework variants"

For distributing several xcframeworks you can [create Swift package](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-binary-frameworks-as-swift-packages) with several `.binaryTarget` items in `targets` section