# How to load framework at runtime in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, llvm, lipo

I have a third party framework `customx.framework` *(iOS)* `customx.framework` *(Simulator)*.

To run project on simulator `customx.framework` *(Simulator)* to be imported & for device
`customx.framework` *(iOS)* to be imported

simultaneously importing is not supported by xcode

At present i am manually importing framework, so i am looking for runtime scrip changes or combined (iOS+Simulator) framework to import in xcode project.

For that

1. I have tried `lipo` & `libtool` but seems didn't worked.
2. I used ***validate workspace*** but it fails when importing modules.

tried links -

[iOS merge several framework into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843617/ios-merge-several-framework-into-one)

[Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked framework '****.framework' was built for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267897/building-for-ios-simulator-but-the-linked-framework-framework-was-built)

Comment: A Swift Package might be what you are looking for. you have much more control.

Comment: @loremipsum any more hint please ?

Comment: I don't have an exact sample but I'll post some links that helped me figure it out before. I don't do this often, but I know it took me a while to figure out your `framework` has to become an [XCFramework](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/416) and then `XCFramework` can be used with [Swift Package Manager](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/408) the process isn't as straightforward as you would think. Once you get a package going it is really easy to manage. There are other WWDC videos on the topic. I wish I could be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

> simultaneously importing is not supported by Xcode

Supported. It is named *XCFramework*.

So assuming each variant of frameworks have been built correctly (pay attention that `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES`, just in case - Xcode set it to YES automatically), join them in terminal  or Xcode script phase with next command:

```
$ xcodebuild -create-xcframework 
      -framework "/full_path_to_iOS_variant/customx.framework" 
      -framework "/full_path_to_Simulator_variant/customx.framework" 
      -output "/full_path_to_result/customx.xcframework"
```

and then add it once in target dependency

[image: demo]

and that's it.

Comment: It's Helpful. But i have readymade framework(No source code access) so when i run command i get error like .. `No swift interface file found within framework` @Asperi

Comment: Ok, not sure how you get that and why swift is there, but actually you can construct this wrapping XCFramework manually, it is only a bundle around existing frameworks with some info in plist. This article should be helpful https://appspector.com/blog/xcframeworks.

Answer (score 1):

You can archive for iOS device and iOS simulator and merge them to one xcframework. This is my current project xcodebuild command for it.

```
- Archive for iOS devices
xcodebuild archive \
-scheme Framework-scheme \
-configuration Release \
-destination 'generic/platform=iOS' \
-archivePath './build/native/Framework-Name.framework-iphoneos.xcarchive' \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES


- Archive for iOS simulator
xcodebuild archive \
-scheme Framework-scheme \
-configuration Release \
-destination 'generic/platform=iOS Simulator' \
-archivePath './build/native/Framework-Name.framework-iphonesimulator.xcarchive' \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

- build framework from archives
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
-framework './build/native/AdTrue-Native.framework-iphoneos.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/Framework-Name.framework' \
-framework './build/native/AdTrue-Native.framework-iphonesimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/Framework-Name.framework' \
-output './build/native/Framework-Name.xcframework'
```